# How to make table wrap to other column in multicols environment

Tags: tables, multicol

I'm making an equation sheet for an upcoming final, and in this includes a massive table of terms.

[image: Really long table]

But since I'm making this in a two column environment, I would ideally have the table be split between the two columns once it hits the end of a page / etc. Something like this.
[image: Split between two columns]

My current code looks something like this:

```
\begin{multicols}{2}

\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c c|l|}
        \hline
        \textbf{Symbol} & & \textbf{Description} \\
        \hline
        $A$ & & Amps (C/s) \\

        ...        

        $\tau_p$ & & hole minority-carrier lifetime \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{List of Symbols}
\end{table}

\end{multicols}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use a tabular-like environment for the material at hand. Instead, given that what you have looks very much like a list of pair-wise items, I would use a `description` environment. One of the (many!) useful features of list-like environments (such as `itemize`, `enumerate`, and `description`) is that breaking material across columns and even pages is an entirely normal affair that doesn't require making any special efforts.

I would definitely use the `\si` macro, which is provided by the `siunitx` package, to typeset the scientific units.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably
\usepackage{multicol,siunitx,amssymb,enumitem,ragged2e}
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol,inter-unit-product={\cdot}}
\newlength\mylen
\settowidth\mylen{$\si{\joule}_{N\mid\mathit{drift}}$} % widest symbol

\begin{document}
\subsection*{Symbols and Descriptions} % choose an appropriate header

\begin{multicols}{2} % use 'multicols*' if column-balancing is not desired
\RaggedRight
\begin{description}[labelwidth=\mylen,nosep]

\item[\si{\ampere}] Amps (\si{\coulomb\per\second})
\item[$D_N$] electron diffusion coefficient (\si{\centi\meter\squared\per\second})
\item[$\mathcal{E}$] Electric field
\item[$\dots$]
\item[\si{\joule}] Joule (\si[per-mode=reciprocal]{\kilo\gram\meter\squared\per\second\squared})
\item[\si{\joule}] Joule (\si{\ampere\per\centi\meter\squared})
\item[$\si{\joule}_{N\mid\mathit{diff}}$] electron diffusion current density
\item[$\si{\joule}_{N\mid\mathit{drift}}$] electron drift current density
\item[$\si{\joule}_{P\mid\mathit{diff}}$] hole diffusion current density
\item[$\si{\joule}_{P\mid\mathit{drift}}$] hole drift current density
\item[$\dots$]
\item[\si{\volt}] Voltage (\si[per-mode=reciprocal]{\kilo\gram\meter\squared\per\second\cubed\per\ampere})
\item[$\dots$]
\item[$N_v$] effective density of valence band states
\item[$\dots$]
\item[$\tau_n$] electron minority-carrier lifetime
\item[$\tau_p$] hole minority-carrier lifetime

\end{description}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I did not realize that description and the si units were a thing, thank you much!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `supertabular` and `\twocolumn` as shown in the following example. (Depending on your documentclass and if the whole document should be typeset in two columns you might also be interested in the `twocolumn` option.)

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{supertabular}

\begin{document}
\twocolumn
\tablehead{    \textbf{Symbol} &  \textbf{Description} \\ \hline}
\bottomcaption{a caption}
\begin{supertabular}{|c l|}
    $A$ &  Amps (C/s) \\
    $\tau_p$ &  hole minority-carrier lifetime \\
        $A$ &  Amps (C/s) \\
    $\tau_p$ &  hole minority-carrier lifetime \\
        $A$ &  Amps (C/s) \\
    $\tau_p$ &  hole minority-carrier lifetime \\
        $A$ &  Amps (C/s) \\
    $\tau_p$ &  hole minority-carrier lifetime \\
        $A$ &  Amps (C/s) \\
    $\tau_p$ &  hole minority-carrier lifetime \\
        $A$ &  Amps (C/s) \\
    $\tau_p$ &  hole minority-carrier lifetime \\
        $A$ &  Amps (C/s) \\
    $\tau_p$ &  hole minority-carrier lifetime \\
        $A$ &  Amps (C/s) \\
    $\tau_p$ &  hole minority-carrier lifetime \\
        $A$ &  Amps (C/s) \\
    $\tau_p$ &  hole minority-carrier lifetime \\
        $A$ &  Amps (C/s) \\
    $\tau_p$ &  hole minority-carrier lifetime \\
        $A$ &  Amps (C/s) \\
    $\tau_p$ &  hole minority-carrier lifetime \\
        $A$ &  Amps (C/s) \\
    $\tau_p$ &  hole minority-carrier lifetime \\
        $A$ &  Amps (C/s) \\
    $\tau_p$ &  hole minority-carrier lifetime \\
        $A$ &  Amps (C/s) \\
    $\tau_p$ &  hole minority-carrier lifetime \\
        $A$ &  Amps (C/s) \\
    $\tau_p$ &  hole minority-carrier lifetime \\
        $A$ &  Amps (C/s) \\
    $\tau_p$ &  hole minority-carrier lifetime \\
        $A$ &  Amps (C/s) \\
    $\tau_p$ &  hole minority-carrier lifetime \\
        $A$ &  Amps (C/s) \\
    $\tau_p$ &  hole minority-carrier lifetime \\
        $A$ &  Amps (C/s) \\
    $\tau_p$ &  hole minority-carrier lifetime \\
        $A$ &  Amps (C/s) \\
    $\tau_p$ &  hole minority-carrier lifetime \\
        $A$ &  Amps (C/s) \\
    $\tau_p$ &  hole minority-carrier lifetime \\
        $A$ &  Amps (C/s) \\
    $\tau_p$ &  hole minority-carrier lifetime \\
        $A$ &  Amps (C/s) \\
    $\tau_p$ &  hole minority-carrier lifetime \\
        $A$ &  Amps (C/s) \\
    $\tau_p$ &  hole minority-carrier lifetime \\
        $A$ &  Amps (C/s) \\
    $\tau_p$ &  hole minority-carrier lifetime \\
        $A$ &  Amps (C/s) \\
    $\tau_p$ &  hole minority-carrier lifetime \\
            $A$ &  Amps (C/s) \\
    $\tau_p$ &  hole minority-carrier lifetime \\
        $A$ &  Amps (C/s) \\
    $\tau_p$ &  hole minority-carrier lifetime \\
        $A$ &  Amps (C/s) \\
    $\tau_p$ &  hole minority-carrier lifetime \\
        $A$ &  Amps (C/s) \\
    $\tau_p$ &  hole minority-carrier lifetime \\
        $A$ &  Amps (C/s) \\
    $\tau_p$ &  hole minority-carrier lifetime \\
        $A$ &  Amps (C/s) \\
    $\tau_p$ &  hole minority-carrier lifetime \\
    \hline

\end{supertabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Depending on the width of the contents of your description column, you might also want to consider using a `p` type column that allows for automated linebreaks.